# Merging Multiple TextViews onto a Bitmap - should i use canvas?

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap

I have found that you can add or merge `textviews` onto a `bitmap`. I have 4 `textviews` that I would like to merge onto the top of the `image`.

Here is a screenshot of what I would like to achieve (although at the minute this is textviews at the top separate to the image):

*the image is below the textviews. Image header in top right is for what image No it is*

[image: Textviews with Image]

So what I am trying to do is once I click the `send` button it "prints" or merges these Textviews onto the `image bitmap` below so that I can then save or send the image(with the `textviews` in it) as one file to my server/device.

So far I have used `Canvas.draw()` method although it seems to overwrite each other and I am trying to keep the same layout as the screenshot.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomLayID"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:padding="8dp"
            >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Detail work order"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Image"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1.5"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:padding="8dp"
            >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1.5"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomLayID"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Open Camera"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Send Image"
            android:background="#99d72e"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Give background as transparent color and border to textviews.

You can set bitmap to imageview by

```
ImageView mImg;
mImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.(your xml img id));
mImg.setImageBitmap(img);
```